# Qt TreeWidgetItem internal field

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Qt application with a QTreeWidget. In the tree widget I have items associated with internal objects of my application. For that association to work I would like each tree item to hold an internal identification number of the internal object is represents.

What is the recommended way to do that? I couldn't find anything helpful except creating an additional column (and possibly making it hidden).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [data/setData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#setData) with a custom role:

```
item = QTreeWidgetItem()
item.setData(column, QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1, identifier)

identifier = item.setData(column, QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1)
```

Each column can have its own associated data.